# Need changes in the given code for plotting a signal

Tags: pgfplots

I want plot for a square wave pulse. I have written the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=5cm,
height=4cm,
x axis line style={-stealth},
y axis line style={-stealth},
xticklabels={1,2},
xmin=-3,
ymax = 1.5,xmax=3.5,
axis lines*=center,
ytick={-1,1},
xtick={1,2},
ylabel near ticks]
\addplot+[thick,mark=none,const plot]
coordinates
{(-1,0)(0,0) (0,1) (1,-1) (2,0) (3,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I need following changes in the plot:

1. Arrow on left side of x-axis
2. g(t) on vertical axis near the arrow and 't' on horizontal axis near the arrow.
3. `xticks` slight offset from the present position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hopefully i understood you correctly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=5cm,
height=4cm,
xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$g(t)$,               % <---
ticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, fill=white, 
                 inner sep = 1pt, outer sep=2pt},   % <---
xmin=-1.8, xmax=3.5,
ymin=-1.2, ymax = 1.6,
xtick={1,2},
axis lines=middle,                      % <---
x label style={anchor=north east},      % <---
y label style={anchor=north east,
               inner ysep=0pt},         % <---
x axis line style={stealth-stealth},    % <---
set layers = axis on top,               % <---
no marks]

\addplot+[const plot, thick] coordinates {
    (-1,0)(0,0) (0,1) (1,-1) (2,0) (3,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

changes in above mwe in comparison to your are indicated by `% <---`

**addendum:**

for some (unknown) reason you like to shift `xtick` labels. one (relatively simple way) is all of them shift to desired direction, for example to the right, you need to replace definition for `ticklabel style` with two definitions as follows:

```
xticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, fill=white, 
                 xshift=1ex,            % <--- select shift amount according to your wish
                 inner sep = 1pt, outer sep=1pt},   
yticklabel style={font=\footnotesize, inner sep = 1pt},
```

in this case your image become

[image]

Comment: Can value 2 on x axis be offset slightly right or left

Comment: @Ehsa, of course this is possible. for this you should use `extra x ticks`, `extra x tick label`  and ` and `extra x tick style={...}`.  for details see `pgfplots` manual, example on page 336. however, i wouldn't shift  `xtick` label. with this change code become more complicated and result is to my opinion worse than now.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Can you provide the weblink for the pgfplots manual you have referred to.

Comment: manual is part of your `latext` distribution. searching with google will give you nearest CTAN archive with package and documentation. to me is closest http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf